# Open Href link located in I.E. in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer-11

I work for an organization that still uses I.E. We have an external HR site that works best in Chrome.  Is there a way to add a parameter to an href link that will direct the link to open in Chrome?  Or even some javascript that would do that?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there isn't a way to to open a link from one browser to another browser, nor is it possible for browsers to launch another program. With or without JavaScript.

If your organization uses Windows however, you can create a .txt file and paste the following script

```
start chrome https://www.google.com/
```

Then save it as a .bat file. It will open the URL in Chrome upon running.

Comment: Actually I do not know about Google Chrome, but Microsoft Edge can be opened using the URL - `microsoft-edge:url`

Answer (score 0):

You can lower the security settings to allow ActiveX controls to achieve this requirement.

Follow these steps (**local test**): Open IE -> settings -> Internet Options -> Security tab -> Local intranet -> Customer level -> Enable option `Initialize and script ActiveX controls not marked as safe for scripting`.

A simple example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" onclick="openInChrome()">open in Chrome</a>
    <script>
        function openInChrome() {
            var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
            shell.run("chrome.exe https://www.google.com");
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks!  That works in IE, but not Firefox. When I check the auto:config settings in Firefox, it shows the status is locked.  Is that what is causing Firefox to not launch the link in Chrome?

Comment: ActiveX is a Microsoft-proprietary framework. It is supported only in MS products, therefore this solution does not work in Firefox.

Comment: Is there a solution that will work in both Firefox and IE?

Comment: As far as I know, no such solution exists. Moreover, the use of ActiveX is a non-standard method, if you use it, you need to bear the corresponding risk.